# Best Practice on Parse Server Security

Tags: java, android, parse-server

I am actually trying to write a small App where I intend to store the Names and Surnames of users in a Parse Server data base. I would need , for a define user , to read and get the Name and Surname of other users at some point.

I have read that anyone can decompile my APK and extract the App id and the Master Key . For me these values are stored in strings.xml , but I can't understand how I can store them elsewhere , as they are needed to connect to the server.

Is there a way to protect the decompiling in order to preserve the MasterKey? Or should I enforce ACL for those columns (Name and Surname added in the User class) and like read the Name and Surname of other users using Cloud Coud when I need it?

What would be the best practice to do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DO NOT USE MASTER KEY IN A CLIENT APP**

If your master key is compromised then your whole parse instance will be compromised. Instead, use class and object ACL to protect your data. If you need special queries that require master key, do it in server-side or cloud code.

Read this doc carefully: https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#security

Comment: All right, I will try to work on what you both have said. I thought I couldn't connect without the master key, I 'll try without it to see. So the idea is to connect to Parse without the key and if needed use it in cloud coude and secure the server. I' 'll work on that

Comment: @SERGEBENYAMIN, for the connection you need only application id if you didn't define any client key in server. The idea is you need to apply proper ACL in classes and objects to protect data. Master Key is for complex queries that you can't do in client due to ACL, so have to do it in the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are some universal solution for "protect things inside APK".

Google `APK reinforcement`.

Comment: Ok i've seen some c++ encoding I would try on strings. xml to hide masterkey. I ll try proguard too.Thx